# How to add iOS frameworks to a Unity project?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, frameworks

How can I add stuff like AdSupport.framework to a Unity project?
I don't want to add them (on the Xcode side) every single time I do a build for iOS...

Using Unity 4.6.

Update, related:

- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-plugin-how-to-link-ios-framework.156231/
- http://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/frameworks-and-plist-on-ios-outp
- https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Unity-SDK/wiki/Unity-and-Xcode-Project-Setup
- http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/222478/how-do-i-automatically-include-a-framework-with-my.html
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/get-tired-in-dragging-frameworks-and-dependence-in-xcode-try-xuporter.190752/ - https://github.com/onevcat/XUPorter - https://github.com/josh-ruis/XUPorter

Answer (score 1):

Until there is an official way of doing this within the Unity editor, I'll just answer like this:

There is no official way to do this. You have to do this every single time you build an iOS project. Does UT hate iOS?

Or you could check out some 3rd party plugins that try to address the issue. I haven't tried it myself yet but https://github.com/onevcat/XUPorter or one of its forks could do it. It appears 3rd party tools have a hard time keeping up with new Unity and Xcode versions.

Or this: https://github.com/openkit/openkit-unity

Also: Something that would work from day-to-day is to select "Append" at build time instead of replace. That way framework setup is maintained (however splash screens settings seem to be ignored, and possibly other stuff too). It won't work however of you checkout the project on another computer or similar.

Comment: FWIW: I've used a lot of time to make a build script inside Unity. Instead of building using the default method in Unity, I use that script, which does a lot of things like editing the info.plist, but also adds frameworks and extra files and folders to the Xcode project. It uses a 3rd party library/tool to add files to the Xcode project.